# Find and list models

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So, I'm making a school project and I've made a system to give points, and store names and details of classmates, now the part, where I'm stuck, in that I want to be able to make a leaderboard that lists names and points from highest to lowest how would I do that

Comment: Please share your attempts

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question - atleast mention the reason why it was downvoted and provide the oppurtunity to the questioner to modify it. Simply downvoting without comments is not going to help a new comer. You need to understand that it was easier for people who joined earlier to get up votes for their questions and answers. Now it is very difficult because many who joined earlier had already asked basic questions or answered those basic questions and they are still earning votes from those. For a new comer it is really difficult to get votes. Have some consideration for that.

Comment: ```js
Class.find({Score: > 0}).exec(
        function(err, class){
        message.channel.send(`Leaderboard\n ${class.FirstName}`)
    )
}
```
Just to add in info, this is for a discord bot I'm making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query will list the users from score highest to lowest

```
Class.find({Score: { $gt: 0}}).sort({ score: -1 }).exec( function(err, class){ 
    message.channel.send(`Leaderboard\n ${class.FirstName}`) 
})
```

Comment: Leaderboard
 undefined

This is what I get after making a change

Comment: @Arsal You need to give more code or detail to explain, as In the MongoDB query there is no word Leaderboard, so it must be somewhere in your code

Comment: I have made no leaderboard, I've made a mLab db with entries for my class mate, the structure has the field Score: and it's value. I want to make a leaderboard for that and I want to have the highest score on top, I can send the db structure or whatever else you require, I tried using your solution to make a leaderboard but it gives a unexpected token > error for the Score: > 0

Comment: Sorry mate, I copy-pasted Score: > 0 from your question, that's not the right way, updated my answer, we should use {Score: { $gt: 0}}

Comment: {

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);
const Student = require('../models/student');

exports.run = async (client, message, typem) => {
    Student.find({Score: { $gt: 0} }).sort({ score: -1 }).exec( function(err, students){ 
        if (students) {
            message.channel.send(`Leaderboard\n ${students.FullName}`)
        }
    })
};

}

Comment: this is my code to get the leaderboard, I don't know how to properly format it here in stackoverflow xd still giving the undefined error

Comment: @Arsal You have an option to edit your question, check below the question there are options "share  edit  follow ",  Add your code below your question, while editing select you code with mouse and press cltrl+K it will format the code and then save

Answer (score 0):

Given `Users` your models in which are stored names, details and scores of your classmates, here're some solutions to sort based on a specified field (in this case, `score`), using the Mongoose's model built-in [sort](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) function:

```js
Users.find({ Score: > 0 }).sort({ Score: 'asc' }).exec((err, docs) => { ... });

// Another way...

Users.find({ Score: > 0 }).sort({ Score: 'ascending' }).exec((err, docs) => { ... });

// Yet, another way...

Users.find({ Score: > 0 }).sort({ Score: 1 }).exec((err, docs) => { ... });
```

Check out the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) for more.